# Sudden memcopy warnings from QBrush after system update when compiling my program

Tags: qt, gcc

I have no idea why this is happening. But everytime I compile my application with a couple of the Qt versions that I have installed I now get these warnings:

```
In file included from /home/Qt5.9.2/5.9.2/gcc_64/include/QtGui/qbrush.h:50,
                 from /home/Qt5.9.2/5.9.2/gcc_64/include/QtGui/qpalette.h:46,
                 from /home/Qt5.9.2/5.9.2/gcc_64/include/QtWidgets/qwidget.h:48,
                 from /home/Qt5.9.2/5.9.2/gcc_64/include/QtWidgets/qdesktopwidget.h:44,
                 from /home/Qt5.9.2/5.9.2/gcc_64/include/QtWidgets/QDesktopWidget:1,
                 from ../src/../../CommonClasses/SQLConn/../../CommonClasses/common.h:6,
                 from ../src/../../CommonClasses/SQLConn/dbinterface.h:10,
                 from ../src/../../EyeExperimenter/src/sslclient/sslclient.h:10,
                 from ../src/../../EyeExperimenter/src/sslclient/ssldbclient.h:4,
                 from ../src/sslwrapper.h:6,
                 from ../src/main.cpp:3:
/home/Qt5.9.2/5.9.2/gcc_64/include/QtGui/qtransform.h: In member function ‘QTransform& QTransform::operator=(QTransform&&)’:
/home/Qt5.9.2/5.9.2/gcc_64/include/QtGui/qtransform.h:81:46: warning: ‘void* memcpy(void*, const void*, size_t)’ writing to an object of type ‘class QTransform’ with no trivial copy-assignment; use copy-assignment or copy-initialization instead [-Wclass-memaccess]
     { memcpy(this, &other, sizeof(QTransform)); return *this; }
                                              ^
/home/Qt5.9.2/5.9.2/gcc_64/include/QtGui/qtransform.h:57:20: note: ‘class QTransform’ declared here
 class Q_GUI_EXPORT QTransform
```

Can any one tell me what this warning is and, more importantly, how do I get rid of it? From what I've seen it has to do with gcc8 which my system currently has, however I've tried chaging the compiler in the Qt Kits configuration of QtCreator and the warning still appears...

Comment: Changing the compiler in the tools did nothing because Qt kept creating a Makefile that called g++ which was a symlink to g++-8. I "fixed" the problem by recreating the g++ symlink to g++-6. In case it helps anyone else...

Comment: Uh, just disable the warning? It’s harmless.

Comment: Ok. Could you please tell me how? As I use QtCreator for all my compilation I'm not sure where to pass the command line paramter to disable that warning

Answer (score 0):

You use qmake as the build system generator, and then gnu make to actually build stuff - Qt Creator is just a shortcut from typing it all out on the command line :)

You can pass the relevant flag to the compiler by adding the following to your `.pro` file, then re-running qmake on the project (e.g. delete the build folder and build again):

```
QMAKE_CFLAGS_WARN_ON += -Wno-class-memaccess
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_WARN_ON += -Wno-class-memaccess
QMAKE_CFLAGS += -Wno-class-memaccess
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -Wno-class-memaccess
```

Comment: Thanks. Ill try it out as soon as a I'm able. Thanks.